# Prove converge or divergence of the following sequence

Tags: calculus

$a_n=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{n})}{2n-5}$

So far I've gotten to the point of the whole $\epsilon-N$ proof that it converges to $0$.

$|\frac{\sin(\sqrt{n})}{2n-5}| \lt \frac{1}{|2n-5|}$

let $n \gt \frac{5}{2}$

$\lt\frac{1}{2n-5} = \frac{1}{n} *\frac{1}{2-\frac{5}{n}}$

After all the bounding I got it to the point to say

$N=$ max$(\frac{3}{\epsilon},\frac{5}{2})$

I think I'm stuck here though for proving the case where if $N=\frac{5}{2}$

Comment: $N$ is supposed to be an integer and $\frac{5}{2}$ is not an integer. So try choosing $N$ as the next integer larger than both $\frac{3}{\epsilon}, \frac{5}{2}$.

Comment: Just write $N=\max(3/\epsilon,5/2)+1$. And $N$ need not be an integer. That's just what textbooks say to make it easier to read.

Comment: You have a lot of freedom available when choosing $N$.  If $5/2$ is inconvenient, just skip past it by choosing $N > 3$.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to consider $5/2$. Just take the maximum of $3$ or $3/\varepsilon$.

As a side note, this is a common trick and can be applied since you’re considering $n\to\infty$. The moral here is that any “bad” points can be avoided since there are finitely many... just take $N$ larger than one plus the largest “bad” point (or similar).